# Computing Premises from Consequence

Tags: logic, proof, computation

We write '**If A, then B**' to mean that if ***A*** is true, then ***B*** must be true because ***B*** is a logical consequence of ***A*** i.e. it is impossible for ***A*** to be true but ***B*** to be false.

Let us consider one such statement:

'***If S<sub>1</sub> , then S<sub>2</sub>***' is true,
where **S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>** are expressions.

Let it also be the case that :
'***If S<sub>i</sub> , then S<sub>2</sub>***' is true, and let there be many such **S<sub>i</sub>**. For all such **S<sub>i</sub>** and **S<sub>1</sub>**, assume they do not contradict each other, and indeed there is a finite deduction from  *all* **S<sub>i</sub>** and **S<sub>1</sub>** to **S<sub>2</sub>**.

Now for a given **S<sub>2</sub>**, I want to generate a finite conjunction of expressions which, so to speak, *encodes* necessary properties of the premises so that the conclusion (**S<sub>2</sub>** in this case) is  the logical consequence of the premise (*all* such **S<sub>i</sub>**). Ideally, this expression must take in some *input*, and yield some **S<sub>i</sub>**, and with appropriate set of constraints, we should be able to generate all **S<sub>i</sub>**. (For sufficiency, we may append some disjunction expressions as well if need be).

Is there a method to *generate* such an expression?

Comment: Not very clear... Every conjunction with S2$ will have S2 as consequence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am thinking on lines of reverse mathematics. Philosophically, premise is contained in the consequence...so I am looking to encode this contained thing so that I get all premises. I hope it clears something...

Comment: See it this way, S2 is a theorem, derived from Si..

Comment: @Ajax The implication A ∧ B ⊢ A is true and yet the premise A ∧ B is not contained in the conclusion A. The implication A ∧ B ⊢ A ∨ B is also true and you could argue that the premise is sort of contained in the conclusion, but this is not general. Further, it is generally accepted that it is the conclusion which is contained in the premise, not the reverse. Further, given any true implication P₁ ⊢ C, we can always add n **arbitrary** premises Q₁, … Qₙ and still get another true implication P₁ ∧ Q₁ ∧ … ∧ Qₙ ⊢ C.

Comment: @Speakpigeon So are you denying existence of a general expression which, upon some input, generates all such Si whose logical consequence is S2? Clearly that isn't the case, because let Si be Axioms, and let S2 be some theorem. Perhaps we should ignore 'contain' term, I am unable to articulate my point, and didn't mean literal containment.

Comment: "Philosophically, premise is contained in the consequence" is false, and this is why your project can not succeed. It is true, to some extent, in Aristotelian logic, and this is why Kant believed it once, when such restricted logic was all there was. And even then it was only true when there are no extra-logical axioms that also contribute to the consequence. In general, S2 can be implied by premises with concepts not even alluded to in S2, and so nothing finite can "encode" them. Reverse mathematics only works when the form of premises is severely constrained by pragmatic context.

Comment: By conjunction I mean to say let's find necessary properties which must be held by all Si so that S2 is derivable from them... If we go all the way back, we reach all intermediate theorems and finally the starting point -the axioms. By enumerating necessary expressions (hence conjunction), I want to, by inputting some input, generate the axioms and all intermediate theorems.

Comment: @Ajax "*are you denying*" Yes and it is obvious it cannot possibly work. If you could derive all possible premises P₁ ∧ P₁ ∧ … ∧ Pₙ from a conclusion C, then the premises would follow from the conclusion, which would makes the implication an equivalence, and the conclusion therefore equivalent to the conjunction of premises, and then this would no longer be the general case but a trivial case of P₁ ∧ P₁ ∧ … ∧ Pₙ⇔.C.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I didn't think of it that way... Just a misadventure: what if I could, hypothetically, use some extra axiom to move from conclusion C to possible premises... Perhaps that will circumvent the legitimate contradiction you have highlighted...

Comment: @Ajax Adding to the conclusion to infer the premise will move it ever closer to equivalence with the premises. The idea cannot work.

Comment: @Conifold Can you explain your point on extra-logical axioms, what they are, usage and probably some simple illustration.

Comment: The premise of the Pythagorean theorem (the triangle is right angled) is not contained in its conclusion. The conclusion only obtains when Euclidean axioms are added to the premise. In hyperbolic geometry triangles satisfying the Pythagorean relation are not right angled, for example. And one can not extract Euclidean axioms from Pythagorean relation alone without some strong prior restriction on what types of axioms are allowed.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks.